# using http source for saving files(different extension) in HDFS with same extension

Tags: hadoop, spring-xd

I need to create a data pipe line where source is HTTP and Sink is HDFS to post data and files. Problem is i want to save files with the same extension as they originally sent to the HTTP source.

I created a stream with below script

Stream create httpToHdfs --defination "http | HDFS" --deploy

but when I am uploading files in .gzip /.xml / .json format it stores files in .txt

I just want to copy file in HDFS through HTTP source, is it possible with spring xd?

Answer (score 0):

The `hdfs` sink is used for writing a text based stream to hdfs. It takes an option named `--fileExtension` where you can specify your file extension. This sink isn't meant for copying a binary file as is though, you would have to use a custom batch job for this and have your http source send a message to the batch job once a file is available. There is a provided batch job `filepollhdfs` that does something similar for CSV files.